# Creating struct with values from function parameter Vec<String>and returning Vec<struct> to caller

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

The purpose of my program is to read questions/answers from a file (line by line), and create several `struct`s from it, put into a `Vec` for further processing.

I have a rather long piece of code, which I tried to separate into several functions (full version on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3ebd1f06f28a12354a9a72064c871ab); hopefully is valid link).

I suppose I'm not understanding a lot about borrowing, lifetimes and other things. Apart from that, the given examples from all around I've seen, I'm not able to adapt to my given problems.

Tryigin to remodel my struct fields from `&str` to `String` didn't change anything. As it was with creating `Vec<Question>` within `get_question_list`.

Function of concern is as follows:

```
fn get_question_list<'a>(mut questions: Vec<Question<'a>>, lines: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Question<'a>> {

    let count = lines.len();

    for i in (0..count).step_by(2) {

        let q: &str = lines.get(i).unwrap();
        let a: &str = lines.get(i + 1).unwrap();

        questions.push(Question::new(q, a));

    }

    questions

}
```

This code fails with the compiler as following (excerpt):

```
error[E0597]: `lines` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:126:23
    |
119 | fn get_question_list<'a>(mut questions: Vec<Question<'a>>, lines: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Question<'a>> {
    |                      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
126 |         let a: &str = lines.get(i + 1).unwrap();
    |                       ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
127 | 
128 |         questions.push(Question::new(q, a));
    |         ----------------------------------- argument requires that `lines` is borrowed for `'a`
...
163 | }
    | - `lines` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Call to get_question_list is around:

```
    let lines: Vec<String> = content.split("\n").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();

    let counter = lines.len();

    if counter % 2 != 0 {
        return Err("Found lines in quiz file are not even (one question or answer is missing.).");
    }

    questions = get_question_list(questions, lines);

    Ok(questions)
```

Comment: You almost certainly want `Question` to hold a `String`, not a `&str`. Just the fact that you have a lifetime associated with `Question` shows that (unless you know what you're doing) you're taking an approach that is either unnecessarily hard or (as in this case) outright wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `Questions` are supposed to borrow something (hence the lifetime annotation), but `lines` gets *moved* into the function, so when you create a new question from a line, it's borrowing *function-local data*, which is going to be destroyed at the end of the function. As a consequence, the questions you're creating can't escape the function creating them.

Now what you could do is *not move the `lines` into the function*: `lines: &[String]` would have the lines be owned by the caller, which would "fix" `get_question_list`.

However the exact same problem exists in `read_questions_from_file`, and there it can not be resolved: the `lines` are read from a file, and thus are necessarily local to the function (unless you move the lines-reading to `main` and `read_questions_from_file` only borrows them as well).

Therefore the simplest proper fix is to change `Question` to *own* its data:

```
struct Question {
    question: String,
    answer: String
}
```

This way the question itself keeps its data alive, and the issue goes away.

We can improve things further though, I think:

First, we can strip out the entire mess around newlines by using [`String::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), it will handle cross-platform linebreaks, *and will strip them*.

It also seems rather odd that `get_question_list` takes a vector by value only to append to it and immediately return it. A more intuitive interface would be to either:

1. take the "output vector" by `&mut` so the caller can pre-size or reuse it across multiple loads, which doesn't really seem useful in this case
2. or create the output vector internally, which seems like the most sensible case here

Here is what I would consider a more pleasing version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0d440d67654b92c75d136eba2bba0c1

```rust
fn read_questions_from_file(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<Question>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_content = read_file(filename)?;
    let lines: Vec<_> = file_content.lines().collect();
    if lines.len() % 2 != 0 {
        return Err(Box::new(OddLines));
    }

    let mut questions = Vec::with_capacity(lines.len() / 2);
    for chunk in lines.chunks(2) {
        if let [q, a] = chunk {
            questions.push(Question::new(q.to_string(), a.to_string()))
        } else {
            unreachable!("Odd lines should already have been checked");
        }
    }
    Ok(questions)
}
```

Note that I inlined / removed `get_question_list` as I don't think it pulls its weight at this point, and it's both trivial and very specific.

Here is a variant which works similarly but with different tradeoffs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b8f95aef5bcae904545617749086dbc

```rust
fn read_questions_from_file(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<Question>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_content = read_file(filename)?;
    let mut lines = file_content.lines();
    
    let mut questions = Vec::new();
    while let Some(q) = lines.next() {
        let a = lines.next().ok_or(OddLines)?;
        questions.push(Question::new(q.to_string(), a.to_string()));
    }

    Ok(questions)
}
```

it avoids collecting the `lines` to a `Vec`, but as a result has to process the file to the end before it knows that said file is suitable, and it can't preallocate `Questions`.

At this point, because we do not care for `lines` being a `Vec` anymore, we could operate on a `BufRead` and strip out `read_file` as well:

```rust
fn read_questions_from_file(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<Question>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file_content = BufReader::new(File::open(filename)?);
    let mut lines = file_content.lines();
    
    let mut questions = Vec::new();
    while let Some(q) = lines.next() {
        let a = lines.next().ok_or(OddLines)?;
        questions.push(Question::new(q?, a?));
    }

    Ok(questions)
}
```

The extra `?` are because while `str::Lines` yields `&str`, `io::Lines` yields `Result<String, io::Error>`: IO errors are reported lazily when a read is attempted, meaning every line-read could report a failure if `read_to_string` would have failed.

OTOH since `io::Lines` returns a `Result<String, ...>` we can use `q` and `a` directly without needing to convert them to `String`.